# RobotFramework/Python: Parameterizing errors for required fields

Tags: python, excel, robotframework

I have a general comment looking for some feedback: I would like to check for errors on required fields. These can occur generally on the page (ex: "please correct and  resubmit the highlighted errors...") as well as on required text fields (ex: "First Name is required..."). I would like to include these specific errors in my xls data file as a cell comment. This way one cell can have script UI data as well as the expected error for that specific field. One of the issues I'm finding is that 1) Robot Framework & Python don't support reading a cell comment (at least that's what my research is showing. Xlrd module has something but it's undocumented and requires a lot of experimentation to figure out) and 2) the Excel COM object requires MS Excel to be installed on the all the test machines. Anyone have any ideas on how to do this or if there's a better approach?

Comment: Perhaps stating the obvious, but why store this information in an Excel cell comment? Why not a regular cell?

Comment: This way I can have script UI data as well as the expected error for that specific field in ONE cell.